# drupal: Should I use 6 still?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'm looking to build a shopping cart website with upsell features to provide users with "customers also bought" and "customers also viewed." The problem is, I can't seem to find modules in drupal 7 that do this, all the ones I can find are for drupal 6. How smart of a move overall is it to build a new website using drupal 6?

Answer (score 1):

At any given time, there are two major release series of Drupal which are supported. Currently, these are Drupal 6 and Drupal 7.
Official support for Drupal 6 will stop when Drupal 8 is officially released. This should occur at some point this year.

In short, you should not be starting a new project in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch from Ubercart to Drupal Commerce, you'll have a better chance of finding the modules you need for Drupal 7.